# Android Foreground Service Crashed

Tags: android, android-layout, service

I have been facing issues with Android service and their restart behavior. At present i have a Service (SERVICE 1) and a thread which is used to move files from one folder to the other. This works great.

But when I am in my app and start the moving service, and i swipe the app away from recent tasks(systemui.RecentTasks) screen the service is stopped with a log "Scheduling restart of crashed service". This service is a foreground service with an active notification.

I do have another service (SERVICE 2) which is also a foreground service with notification. This service also creates a thread to run a background operation. But when I swipe the app this service is not killed and there is not log from ActivityManager.

The final scenario is when the SERVICE 1 stopped frequently from recent tasks within small intervals , again and again, the SERVICE 2 is also stopped now with the same log. I can understand this, as the system detects frequent crash from this app, it tries give less priority to it even if it has foreground service.

My question is why this strange behavior. Both are running in foreground and with an active notification. why does the SERVICE 1 Is stopped and SERVICE 2 is not? I don't find enough resources of service restart behavior when it is crashed. Also i don't find information as how the android system manages to schedule a restart. FYI SERVICE 1 returns START_REDELIVER_INTENT and SERVICE 2 returns START_STICKY.

Kindly help me with this issue. Please. Thanks